# How does internet filter works between remote desktop and local desktop environment using Dell SonicWall

Tags: remote-desktop

I am remoting to the work using Dell SonicWall.

While I am using remote desktop and access work computer, the work internet filter applies.
Which makes sense.

However, even while connecting to the company network via SonicWall, my local desktop does not have filter applied.

How does this work? If I connect to company network, doesn't that mean my network overall is connected to the company network, thus filter should be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons this might be.

The filter may simply not be applied to the VPN network traffic.  Your work computer will be on a separate local subnet to the VPN traffic and the filter may only be applied to the local subnet, not the VPN one.

Second, A VPN connection can be run in two different configuration.

- **Tunnel All** - All your traffic is run through the VPN
- **Split Tunnel** - Only traffic with a destination at the remote site is run through the VPN.

Tunnel all provides the best control/ease of use at the cost of bandwidth.  By running all traffic through the VPN the VPN host needs to have enough bandwidth available to support the extra general internet traffic rather than just the site-specific traffic.

Split Tunneling allows the VPN host to deal with only the site-specific traffic and allow the other general internet traffic to instead use the end user's normal internet connection, saving the host's bandwidth.

One way to check for split tunneling is to use [a site that shows your IP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip) and see if the IP matches when connected vs not connected to the VPN.  If the IP is the same, you're split-tunneled.  If it changes, you're in tunnel all.